# How to mock Kernel.open or open-uri without calling Kernel explicitly?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, tdd, open-uri

How to mock this call in RSpec?

```
require 'open-uri'
class FileFoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def download image_url
    open("tmp/#{file}", 'wb') do |file|
      file << open(image_url).read
    end
  end
end
```

Tried mocking FileFoo.open, but this did not work because I am using the downloaded file, not the return value.

Changed code to `file << Kernel.open(image_url).read`, and used the following:

```
Kernel.stub_chain(:open, :read).and_return(File.read image_fixture)
```

This works fine, but is there a way to mock `Kernel.open().read`, without calling Kernel explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

Often times I think that a better test in this situation is not to mock specific filesystem calls, but instead stub out the filesystem with a gem like [fakefs](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs).

I talk more about it a blog post called [Fake It!](http://highgroove.com/articles/2011/12/06/fake-it.html).

The idea is that stubbing specific filesystem calls is quite brittle, but writing to the actual filesystem is not necessarily desirable in a unit test either. Something like **fakefs** is a nice happy medium a lot of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is difficult because the design of the method `download` is poor. It is doing 2 things:

1. Fetching the file via HTTP
2. Saving it to disk

These ***separate functions*** should both be tested, and the first should be mocked. I don't see any reason to mock the filesystem because saving the file (which is small) is fast and easily tested.

If the method were broken into 2 methods, then:

1. `fetch with http` would return the file.
2. `save file` would save it.

This approach makes the mocking and testing simple.